# how to stop function from executing again until a certain time has passed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that runs when you click a button. However I don't want the function to execute again until a certain time has passed. For example, the countdown has finished. If the button is clicked again the function should not run.

```js
$("start").on('click', function() {
  var myTimer;

  function clock() {
    myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
    var c = 5;

    function myClock() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = --c;
      if (c == 0) {
        clearInterval(myTimer);
        alert("Reached zero");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you should hide or otherwise disable the button until your countdown is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly remove the `clock()` function. It serves no purpose given the structure of your code. Secondly, if you're going to use a framework such as jQuery, be consistent with it.

To address the actual issue, store a boolean flag to determine if the time is running or not.

```js
let $demo = $('#demo');

$("#start").on('click', function() {
  let $button = $(this);
  if ($button.data('running'))
    return; // do nothing

  $button.data('running', true);
  let myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
  let c = 5;
  $demo.html(c);

  function myClock() {
    $("#demo").html(--c);
    if (c == 0) {
      $button.data('running', false);
      clearInterval(myTimer);
      console.log("Reached zero");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: If you don't mind answering this, if there are multiple buttons with the class .start replacing the id #start, how would I achieve the same effect without each button speeding up the timer?

Comment: Is there one global timer, or one timer per button elemen?

Comment: there is only a global timer

Comment: In that case change the `#start` selector to a class and put the `data` attribute on the single `#demo` instead